# Console error not showing in ng-show

Tags: ng-show

Hi I have a registration form with the following code:

```
  $scope.signUp = function() {
      if (!$scope.regForm.$invalid) {
       var email = $scope.user.email;
           var password = $scope.user.password;
           if (email && password) {
               auth.$createUser( {email: email, password: password})
                   .then(function() {
                       // do things if success
                       console.log('User creation success');
                       $location.path('/home');
                   }, function(error) {
                       // do things if failure
                       console.log(error);
                       $scope.regError = true;
                       $scope.regErrorMessage = error.message;
                   });
                }
             }
          };
```

And an error message which should appear displaying the same contents as the console if regError is true.

```
  <button type="button" ng-click="signUp();" ng-disabled="!user.email || !user.password" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
  <p style="color:red;" ng-show="regError">{{regErrorMessage}}</p>
```

I don't quite understand what is happening here but the normal form validation works as well as the console output of the Error but the regErrorMessage never shows up. Can anyone see anything obvious? Why would the console work fine but not ng-show?

Answer (score 0):

You should use braces `{{regError}}`